# аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Пытаюсь получить hwid моего hdd диска!
Это работает у другого человека в Dll , а я пытаюсь сделать консольное приложение для вывода hwid!
Вот код https://pastebin.com/L0biV1TX
Компилятор выдает следующее

аргумент типа "const char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"    ConsoleApplication5 c:\Users\Александр\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5.cpp 21

И отмечает красным вот это "C:\" после GetVolumeInformation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714013/argument-of-type-const-char-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type-lpcwstr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавил рядом с `"C:\" L` получилось `L"C:\"`

Comment: Лучше заменить на `TEXT("C:\\")`. Так программа будет компилироваться и при отсутствии макроопределений `_UNICODE` и `UNICODE`.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/239666)

Comment: @Sublihim, это не дополнение, а полноценное решение проблемы, то есть ответ.

Comment: @Arhad это развернутый ответ на вопрос?